# how to get cookie in react passed from express js api (MERN stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I have an api in express js that stores token in cookie on the client-side (react). The cookie is generated only when the user logins into the site. For example, when I test the login api with the postman, the cookie is generated as expected like this:

[image]

But when I log in with react.js then no cookie is found in the browser. Looks like the cookie was not passed to the front end as the screenshot demonstrates below:

[image]

As we got an alert message this means express api is working perfectly without any error!!

Here is my index.js file on express js that includes `cookie-parser` middleware as well

```
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5050;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')



connect_db();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors());
app.use("/" , authRouter);



app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log("Server is running!!");
})
```

Code for setting up the cookie from express api only `controller`

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


const login = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        const checkDetails = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (checkDetails) {
            const { password: hashedPassword, token, username } = checkDetails;
            bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, function (err, matched) {
                if (matched) {
                    res.cookie("token", token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (5 * 60000)) , httpOnly: true }).json({ "message": "You logged in sucessfully!" });
                } else {
                    res.status(500).json({ "message": "Wrong password" });
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ "message": "Wrong email" });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

Here is the react.js code that I am using to fetch data from api without using a proxy in `package.json` file

```
    if (errors.length === 0) {

      const isLogin = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });
      const res = await isLogin.json();
      if(res) alert(res.message);
    }
```

I want to get to know what is the reason behind this "getting cookie in postman but not in the browser". Do I need to use any react package?

The network tab screenshot might help you.
`If I see in the network tab I get the same cookie, set among the other headers`
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code of how you send the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, `fetch` doesn't send requests with the cookies your browser has stored for that domain, and similarly, it doesn't store any cookies it receives in the response. This seems to be the expected behaviour of fetch.

To override this, try setting the credentials option when making the request, like so:

```js
fetch(url, {  
  // ...
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```

or, alternatively:

```js
fetch(url, {  
  // ...
  credentials: 'same-origin'  
})
```

You can read more about the differences between the two [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

Comment: I tried the code you mentioned above but using that line of code, even the request does not generate.  But if I see the network tab with the request fulfilled I can see the cookie in the headers among the other headers f the request to the server. I have added the image in the above questing. Please watch it and suggest to me the best solution. I hope it will help us a lot.

Comment: This problem is not with the ejs template engine i tested that as well. The cookies is getting displayed there but not working for react.js.Any solution???

Answer (score 0):

I got my error resolved with two changings in my code

In front end just added `credentials: 'include'`

```
      fetch(url, {  
         method : "POST"
         body : body,
         headers : headers,
         credentials: 'include'  
      })
```

And in back end just replaced `app.use(cors());` to

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true, exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie', 'Date', 'ETag'] }))
```

That's it got resolved, Now I have cookies stored in my browser!!! Great. Thanks to this article:

```
https://www.anycodings.com/2022/01/react-app-express-server-set-cookie-not.html
```

Answer (score 0):

during development i also faced same things, let me help you that how i solve it,

Firstly you use proxy in your react package.json, below private one:-

```
"private": true,
"proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:5000",
```

mention the same port on which your node server is running
Like:-

```
app.listen(5000,'127.0.0.1',()=>{
console.log('Server is Running');
});
```

above both must be on same , now react will run on port 3000 as usual but now we will create proxy to react So, react and node ports get connected on same with the help of proxy indirectly.

Now, when you will make GET or POST request from react then don't provide full URL, only provide the path on which you wants to get hit in backend and get response,

Example:-
React side on sending request, follow like this:-

const submitHandler=()=>{

```
    axios.post('/api/loginuser', 
    {mobile:inputField.mobile,password:inputField.password})
    .then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    })
    }

 Node side where it will hit:-
app.post('/api/loginuser', async(req,res)=>{
//Your Code Stuff Here          
res.send()
}
```

on both side same link should hit, it is very important

it will 100%.
don't forget to mention

on node main main where server is listening